# RavenDb index, splitting fields, no hit on first item in split

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I'm trying to create and index so that I can search on multiple fields within the document ([This is what I'm trying to do](http://ayende.com/blog/152833/orders-search-in-ravendb)). I've created this test class to illustrate what I am trying to do. My problem is this, in the index I split up the `Note` field so that any word in the `Note` will be searchable. However I've noticed that if I do a search with the first word or letter, in the test that would be 'A' I get no hits, but if I search with a 'B' a get at hit, can't figure out why that is.

```
public class Sandbox
{
    [Fact]
    public void Run_Forrest_Run()
    {
        var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
        {
            RunInMemory = true, 
            Conventions = { DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites }
        };

        store.Initialize();
        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(SearchExpenseIndex).Assembly, store);

        using (store)
        {
            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Store(new Expense
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Today,
                    Category = "Transport",
                    Amount = 1000,
                    Note = "A B C"
                });

                session.SaveChanges();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // var terms = new[] {"A"}; <-- THIS WILL FAIL
            var terms = new[] {"B"};

            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                var result = session.Query<SearchExpenseIndex.ReduceResult, SearchExpenseIndex>()
                                .Where(x => x.Query.In(terms))
                                .As<Expense>()
                                .Select(x => new 
                                {
                                    Id = x.Id,
                                    Category = x.Category,
                                    Date = x.Date,
                                    Amount = x.Amount,
                                    Note = x.Note
                                }).ToList();


                Assert.Equal(1, result.Count);

            }
        }
    }

    public class Expense
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchExpenseIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Expense, SearchExpenseIndex.ReduceResult>
    {
        public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string Query { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }

        public SearchExpenseIndex()
    {
        Map = documents => from d in documents
            select new
            {
                Query = new object[]
                {
                    d.Category,
                    d.Note,
                    d.Note.Split(' '),
                    d.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Pelle,
The character 'A' is a stop word in English. As such, you can't really search on it, because just about any search term is going to have it there.

Comment: Yes, that is true, I guess that was a bad example on my part =). However if I change the note to be  `SOME OTHER VALUES` and search for 'SOME' I get the same result, which is no result in the test. Seems like the first value in the split is not getting indexed.